# MS Access 2013 : Reserved error ( -7713 ): There is no message for this error

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2013, linked-tables

In MS Access 2013, an error displays after trying to open/view a Query: Reserved error (-7713): There is no message for this error

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had Table relink performed (it was linking to an SQL Server) and I had deleted a column (as well as added one), which seemed to break that specific Query. Relinking SQL a second time fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Please find solution describe below.

Replace `dbFailonerror` with `dbSeeChanges` when using SQL update Statements

```
"CurrentDb.Execute StrSQL, dbSeeChanges"
```